# IValueConverter Interface explaiantion required?

Tags: ivalueconverter

could anyone explain IvalueConverter interface and its method of convert() and convertback() and specially their arguments :object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language
code snippet:

```
<StackPanel Margin="30">

    <TextBox Name="txtbox"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=txtbox,Path=Text,Converter={StaticResource RC_converter}}" FontSize="14" />

</StackPanel>



public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    double pkr;
    double dollar = 0.0;
    if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out pkr))
    {
        dollar = pkr * 0.0099;
    }
    return dollar;
}
```

Secondly as above method gives me currency in dollar if I enter rupee amount in the text boxes. So what if I change the amount of dollar from second textbox? Do I need to use convertback for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

First you can turn to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701934) for explanation on the arguments. They are explained in details in the Remarks section.

For your usage, you only need to use the first argument in your `Convert` method- which is the amount of rupees- and multiplied by a fixed ratio, and returns the amount of dollars.

The second question: I should say this is an interesting one.

You are right, if you implement the convertback then everything will *almost* work.

```
<TextBox Name="txtbox1" />
<TextBox Name="txtbox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtbox1,Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource RC_converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

You need to do add `Mode=TwoWay` so `ConvertBack` will be called, and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` so when you type on the `Dollar` (2nd) textbox, the `Ruppe` textbox is updated-otherwise it is only updated when Dollar textbox loses focus.

**Important**:

I said it will *almost* work because two textboxes binding to each other is a weird circular chain. You input amount of Rupees and the amount of Dollars is updated, which updates the amount of Rupees. You will see the issue.

```
b = a * 0.0099; //Convert
a = b * 100;    //ConvertBack?????  
b = a * 0.0099; //Convert is called again... and... too bad
```

So the correct way, is let both textboxes binding to a property in ViewModel, again, two-way binding, and implement `convertback` method, and specify `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488617/how-to-perform-wpf-data-binding-if-two-textboxs-values-depends-on-each-otherd), but it is for WPF, just for your reference.

Comment: oka thanks alot ! but now another query is since my app performs 4 types of conversion at the same time. so for that matter i want to send the sign of the particular currency as well like dollar sign  so that it reutrns amount in rupee and like wise. i used  :   xmlns:sys="using:assignment1"<sys:string x:Name="format">$</sys:string>   and then i was trying to send it as convertparameter ! but it gives me an error that string not part of name space.

Comment: `Text="{Binding ElementName=txtbox1,Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource RC_converter}, ConverterParameter=$, ...`, and in code, typecast parameter into a string: `if ((parameter as string) == "$")`